# Can [in] parameters be used for returning data?

Tags: com

I'm not quite sure how `[in]` and `[out]` interact with the pass-by-value and pass-by-reference concepts. The MSDN documentation clearly states that `[in]` means data flows from caller to callee, and `[out]` is required for data to flow from callee to caller.

However someone suggested to me that I use `[in]` parameters for objects where the caller can retrieve the results.

Example method definition in IDL:

```
HRESULT _stdcall a_method( [in] long *arg1, [in] BSTR arg2, [in] IAnObject *arg3 );
```

In my server's implementation of this method (using C++), I can write:

```
*arg1 = 20;
arg2[0] = L'X';    // after checking length of string is not 0
arg3->set_value(50);
```

In the client code, using C++:

```
long val1 = 10;
BSTR val2 = SysAllocString(L"hello");
IAnObject *val3 = AnObject_Factory::Create();  

ptr->a_method(&val1, val2, val3);
```

When I tried this out (using my object via in-process server), all three changes from the server were propagated to the client, i.e. `val1 == 20`, `val2` was `"Xello"`, and `val3->get_value()` got `50`.

My question is: Is this guaranteed behaviour, i.e. if I am using out-of-process server, or DCOM to another machine, will it see the same changes in `val1`, `val2`, and `val3` ?

I previously thought that `[in]` indicated to the underlying RPC that the argument only had to be marshaled in one direction; it didn't have to try and send changes back to the caller.  But now I am not so sure.

I am intending that my object is Automation-compatible (i.e. usable from VB6, Java etc. - no custom marshaling required), and that it ought to be able to be used via DCOM instead of in-process, without any changes required in the client code.

Comment: Use `[in, put]`, not `[in]`. An `[in, out]` parameter contains a value both before the call and after the call. The marshaller will send the value both ways. Note you can't prove anything about the attributes by trying with an in-process server running on the same apartment as the caller (the IDL attributes have no effect on the call because it's a direct call and bypasses the marshaller).

Comment: That would have to be `[in, out] IAnObject **arg4` then?  Where does `arg3->set_value(50);` "go" if it is only `[in]` , or is this a violation of specification?

Comment: OK. So it would work for the client to call `val3->AddRef();` beforehand, and then `val3->get_value()` afterwards?  But perhaps confusing to other developers who were not expecting this behaviour?

Comment: Sorry, my first comment doesn't address your question. You use `[in, out]` to pass *values* both ways. You are trying to use an *object* to pass values in and out. Unless you expect the callee to pass back a new object, you should use `[in]` for the object pointer, just like you were told. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: OK. In the case of `arg1` (for out-of-process or DCOM), what happens is that a `long` is created in the stub (server) which is initialized by a value marshaled from the proxy (client), and `arg1` in the server points to the stub; so even if the server modifies `*arg1` it never is marshaled back to the client because it is `[in]`.  However, with `arg3`, calling `arg3->set_value()` does not set a value in the stub , it makes another cross-process call to the object which is living in an apartment in the client. So the client sees this value.  I think the pieces are falling into place now!

Comment: Matt, the link you found is authoritative. You should post it as an answer and accept it. I'll upvote it as well. I will delete my answer as soon as you post yours, as mine is clearly wrong and helps nobody. I'm very sorry for providing you with bad information; it's not the way I do things. Yesterday late night I was convinced I had it right.

Comment: @EuroMicelli Thanks for posting anyway though as it enabled discussion which did find the right answer in the end.  I'm wary of treating randomly-found MSDN links as authoritative; as Paulo says, occasionally there is misinformation on there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't change the contents of `[in]` arguments, so the following code is wrong:

```
*arg1 = 20;
arg2[0] = L'X';    // after checking length of string is not 0
```

You're seeing the changes being reflected because you're making calls in the same apartment, where marshaling isn't happening.  The proper way to return values is with `[out]` or `[in, out]` arguments.

However, you may access its contents and call its methods (for interface pointers), so the following code is right:

```
arg3->set_value(50);
```

---

EDIT: Further answering your questions.

Marshaling can occur both ways, and the `[in]` and `[out]` attributes tell the way(s).

For automation, I recommend you don't return more than the typical `[out, retval]` argument, to support scripting languages.  If you must return multiple values, return an `IDispatch` with properties.  Take a look at [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2004/07/14/183241.aspx) as a good starting point if you're taking scriptable automation seriously.

Answer (score 0):

To expand upon @Paulo-madeira's answer, I can guarantee that if a proxy is involved, that

```
*arg1 = 20;
arg2[0] = L'X';    // after checking length of string is not 0
```

will *at* *best* be ignored, and at worst will corrupt the heap.